# Could not find method implemnetation() for arguments. Error

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Hi i am getting the followin error on my build gradle `Could not find method implemnetation() for arguments.` I tried to clean the gradle cache clean project but nothing works. I have seen similliar posts but i couldnt find the answer.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'java-library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
        api 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: try "compile" and "testCompile" ("implementation"/ "testImplementation" is newer, may not fit with your gradle version)

Comment: I tried both none work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project and your application module have both a `build.gradle` file.

Here you are mixing the top level `build.gradle`, which should be like this:

**Project `build.gradle`** (Top Level inside your project's folder)

```
//the `java-library` plugin is unnecessary here
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        //the gradle plugin version is the same as Android Studio, here v3.1.1 which is currently the latest stable
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

**App Module `build.gradle`** (Module Level inside you app module's folder)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android{...}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar'
}
```

For more information about these 2 `build.gradle` files, you can refer to the documentation for the [top level](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#top-level) and the [module level](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#module-level)